# Why does this bash command sometimes return a blank string?

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following line to generate a random number:

> head -c 3 /dev/urandom | hexdump | sed -e 's/[0 a-z]//g' | head -c 1

This works fine but sometimes (very few) it returns a new line.
Does anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Short answer:* Your three random bytes match [0a-f]+ in hex.

*Long answer:* The `hexdump` command in your pipe returns an address offset, followed by a space and the hex representation of the three bytes you receive from `head -c 3 /dev/urandom`. The address offset in the first line is always "0000000", so it gets discarded by the `sed` filter, as well as the space after it. So the only relevant thing fed to the `sed` command in the first line is the hex representation of the three `urandom` bytes. But it will happen (randomly ;-)) that the hex representation of all three bytes will consist of the number 0 and the characters `a` through `f`, only. So your `sed` filter will return nothing for the first line, which leaves a single newline. The `head -c 1` at the end of the pipe will filter out the next line from `hexdump`, so you will see nothing.

An example with not so random numbers:

```
# First three bytes with values 4, 5 and 6 octal.
$ echo -n $'\004\005\006' | hexdump 
0000000 0504 0006
0000004

# Because of little endianess, we get the 5 back after the sed and head filters
$ echo -n $'\004\005\006' | hexdump | sed -e 's/[0 a-z]//g' | head -c 1
5

# Now with FF bytes (be aware that it is octal notation), 
# only 'f' and '0' and space are left:
$ echo -n $'\377\377\377' | hexdump 
0000000 ffff 00ff
0000004

# Now filtering this through sed gives nothing back
$ echo -n $'\377\377\377' | hexdump | sed -e 's/[0 a-z]//g' | head -c 1
$
```

You should use `$RANDOM`, as @Iain wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I've no idea why your command is generating a new line but it seems very convoluted. Have you tried working with the bash builtin `$RANDOM` ?

```
echo $(( $RANDOM % 9 ))
```

for example.

There's also lots of apparently less convoluted ways to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194882/generate-random-number) on Stack Overflow.